# Display Item requested by user in template (django)

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-users, django-database

I have a simple borrowing items request app, which the user would log in and fill out a form with the following:

- Item
- Location
- Start date
- End date

This is stored in a database [Record stored in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAYkp.png)

Then I have a return page where the user will confirm that has returned the item by just clicking return.

I want to show the only the related items with the user logged in to the page, (so just the request the user made: the current item and the previous ones.)

I have the following model for the Request Table:

```
class Request(models.Model):
       shootkit_id = models.ForeignKey(Shootkit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
       request_start_date = models.DateField('Start Date')
       request_end_date = models.DateField('End Date')
       location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The following def in views:

```
def return_form(request):
    form = shootkitForm
    request_db = Request.objects.all
    return render(request, 'return_form.html', {'form':form, 'request_db':request_db})
```

And the following on the template return:

```
{% for shootkit in request_db %}
        <div class="callout-info">Hi {{ user }}, you currently have the {{ shootkit.shootkit_id }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
```

Obviously this is showing every single record on the table (if I ahve more that one record). I would like to only display the item (in this case a shootkit #5) linked with the user [User log in info and name of the item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Riun.png)

This is my first development ever and is the first time around using django... So that's the only way I can think how to show the records... but I don't know how to link it with the user and show only the record that the user (logged in) appears in. Can anyone help please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [filter()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#s-retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters):

```
def return_form(request):
    form = shootkitForm
    request_db = Request.objects.filter(username=request.user)
    return render(request, 'return_form.html', {'form':form, 'request_db':request_db})
```

Comment: @E Paul, thank you for the help. 
That makes total sense, although I applied this filter and I get the following error:
in check_query_object_type
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot query "oscar-nl": Must be "User" instance.

Comment: Then do this:  request_db = Request.objects.filter(username=User.objects.get(username=request.user)) . Also, are you signed in?

Comment: @E Paul, yay!! that worked! yes, I am logged in, I have tried with different users and is showing just the items requested by those users!
You are a star my friend! thank you so much for your help!